# ¿Como ordenar una lista de tuplas segun los elementos que contenga?

Tags: python, lista, tuplas

Estoy intentado ordenar una lista de tuplas de mayor a menor según la cantidad de elementos que tenga cada tupla. Por lo que tengo entendido hasta ahora: las tuplas son inmutables. Entonces lo que hice fue pasar esta lista de tuplas a una lista de listas:

```
lista_tuplas = [(1, 2), (1, 2), ("b"), (6, 4, 5, 6), ("a", 9, 1, "b", "c")]

nueva_lista = []

for tuplas in lista_tuplas:

     nueva_lista.append(list(tuplas))
    
nueva_lista.sort()
```

Con sort() me termina dando error. Gracias por alguna ayuda/sugerencia de ante-mano!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno tu problema se resuelve con una expresion lambda en la funcion `sort`, tanto `sort` como `sorted()` aceptan un parametro `key` el cual le indica de acuerdo a que va ordenar la lista

```py
lista_tuplas = [(1, 2), (1, 2), ("b"), (6, 4, 5, 6), ("a", 9, 1, "b", "c")]

#nueva_lista = []
#se utiliza la compresión de lista, es lo mismo que tu ciclo for 
lista_tuplas = [list(tupla) for tupla in lista_tuplas ]

#en key le decimos que lo haga de acuerdo a su longitud
lista_tuplas.sort(key=lambda e:len(e))
print(lista_tuplas)
#[['b'], [1, 2], [1, 2], [6, 4, 5, 6], ['a', 9, 1, 'b', 'c']]
```